# Python Regex no groups after alternation operator

Tags: python, regex

I wrote a regex match pattern in python, but re.match() do not capture groups after | alternation operator.

Here is the pattern:

```
pattern = r"00([1-9]\d) ([1-9]\d) ([1-9]\d{5})|\+([1-9]\d) ([1-9]\d) ([1-9]\d{5})"
```

I feed the pattern with a qualified string: `"+12 34 567890"`:

```
strng = "+12 34 567890"
pattern = r"00([1-9]\d) ([1-9]\d) ([1-9]\d{5})|\+([1-9]\d) ([1-9]\d) ([1-9]\d{5})"
m = re.match(pattern, strng)
print(m.group(1))
```

None is printed.

Buf if I delete the part before | alternation operator

```
strng = "+12 34 567890"

pattern = r"\+([1-9]\d) ([1-9]\d) ([1-9]\d{5})"
m = re.match(pattern, strng)
print(m.group(1))
```

It can capture all 3 groups:

```
12
34
567890
```

Thanks so much for your thoughts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'|'` has nothing to do with the index of group, index is always counted from left to right in the regex itself.

In your original regex, their are 6 groups:

```
In [270]: m.groups()
Out[270]: (None, None, None, '12', '34', '567890')
```

The matching part is the second part, thus you need:

```
In [271]: m.group(4)
Out[271]: '12'
```

Comment: YES... stupid me. thank you very much for clearing it up!! :DDD

Answer (score 0):

You want to support two different patterns, one with `00` and the other with `+` at the start. You may *merge* the alternatives using a [*non-capturing group*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do):

```
import re
strng = "+12 34 567890"
pattern = r"(?:00|\+)([1-9]\d) ([1-9]\d) ([1-9]\d{5})$"
m = re.match(pattern, strng)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
    print(m.group(2))
    print(m.group(3))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SZ0qAO/1) and the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/qSXmNv) yielding

```
12
34
567890
```

The regex at the regex testing site is prepended with `^` (start of string) because `re.match` only matches at the start of the string. The whole pattern now matches:

- `^` - start of string (implicit in `re.match`)
- `(?:00|\+)` - a `00` or `+` substrings
- `([1-9]\d)` - Capturing group 1: a digit from `1` to `9` and then any digit
- - a space (replace with `\s` to match any 1 whitespace chars)
- `([1-9]\d)` - Capturing group 2: a digit from `1` to `9` and then any digit
- - a space (replace with `\s` to match any 1 whitespace chars)
- `([1-9]\d{5})` - Capturing group 3: a digit from `1` to `9` and then any 5 digits
- `$` - end of string.

Remove `$` if you do not need to match the end of the string right after the number.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation! I learnt a new skill (non-capturing group) in your post.

Comment: @Elle Are you sure you do not want the whole string to be matched with your regex? If you do, then my answer is the correct one.